# mutiple source topic and join master topic then produce to final topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have trouble when create kstream from topic source A and B. topic A and B is different schema.
so i build different stream in one project.

here snip my code :

```
String ktableMaster = "TOPIC_NAME_MASTER";

public KStream<String, SchemaA> KstreamA(StreamsBuilder builder) {
    KStream<String, SchemaA> kstreamA = builder.stream(sourceTopicA, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), serdeA))
                        .selectKey("specific-key");
    }
    KStream<String, SchemaA> schemaACompleteKstream = KstreamA.join(ktableMaster, (k, v) -> k, new SchemaCompleteA()); 
    
    schemaACompleteKstream
                .map(new KeyValueMapper<String, SchemaA, KeyValue<? extends String, ? extends SchemaA>>() {
                    @Override
                    public KeyValue<? extends String, ? extends SchemaA> apply(String s, SchemaA SchemaCompleteA) {
                        return new KeyValue<>(null, SchemaCompleteA);
                    }
                }).to(destTopicSchemaA, Produced.with(null, schemaASerdeComplete));
```

then i build code for schema B in same class ,

```
public KStream<String, SchemaB> KstreamB(StreamsBuilder builder) {
    KStream<String, SchemaB> kstreamB = builder.stream(sourceTopicB, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), serdeB))
                        .selectKey("specific-key");
    }
    KStream<String, SchemaB> schemaBCompleteKstream = KstreamB.join(ktableMaster, (k, v) -> k, new SchemaCompleteB());
    
    schemaBCompleteKstream
                .map(new KeyValueMapper<String, SchemaB, KeyValue<? extends String, ? extends SchemaB>>() {
                    @Override
                    public KeyValue<? extends String, ? extends SchemaB> apply(String s, SchemaB SchemaCompleteB) {
                        return new KeyValue<>(null, SchemaCompleteB);
                    }
                }).to(destTopicSchemaB, Produced.with(null, schemaBSerdeComplete));
```

then i get eror like this

> Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topic ktableMaster has already been registered by another source.

I know i can't use one topology in join same topic

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Where else are you using ktableMaster since that's your error?

Comment: sorry,  I already edit,

Comment: Are you able to create two separate StreamsConfig properties, with two StreamBuilders , then run two separate topologies with unique `application.id`?

Comment: i see, let me try with different consumer.group. Thanks anyway @OneCricketeer